# Simulating a request with Hmac signature

Tags: python, networking, python-requests, header, hmac

I am trying to send a request after reverse engineering a private API, but the headers have these two elements that are crucial for the success of sending this request and getting a 200 response:

`x-hmac-signed-body:` and
`x-hmac-signed-result:`.

So my question is, how do I generate these kind of headers to make my request work succufully.